# Configure Apache ActiveMQ Artemis to send AMQP 1.0 connection and link level redirect

Tags: activemq-artemis

How i can  configure Apache ActiveMQ Artemis to send AMQP 1.0 connection-level redirect and link-level redirect to a client that are connected or trying to connect to broker.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the use-case? Perhaps there is another way to accomplish your goal.

Comment: My use case is related to IoT field; I am working with Eclipse Hono project and EnMasse project to implement an IoT platform. And my wish is to have a possibility to migrate a tenant from one cluster to another cluster. So, for this reason i want to have AMQP redirect for business applications that will delivery the new host.

Comment: Have you considered a DNS redirect or some other network-level re-routing (e.g. using iptables)?

Comment: Yes, I implemented a DNS and DNS SRV approach, but  I realized that this solution have a big draw-back; you can't control DNS update on device and application side, and at the end for a while you have inconsistency in  communication, because part of devices  and applications already use  new cluster but other part still pushing data on old one. Regarding net-work level routing i never consider this option because i need something that can operate at AMQP level and for specific tenant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ActiveMQ Artemis doesn't expose the ability to statically configure connection-level or link-level redirects.

Comment: Are any chance to implement this via Apache Qpid dispatcher in front of ActiveMQ Artemis broker ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the configuration details of the Qpid dispatch router.